# Zedboard Booting using SD Card

Tags: zynq

I am trying to boot my Zedboard with SDcard,in this process I want .bif file to move forward but the file was missing or not generated(Actually i don't know exactly). Can anyone please explain me how to Get that file or How to generate that file...?

Comment: Please to be more specific about what development tools and process you are trying to use. Are you following a guide or tutorial? Which steps did you follow so far?